# rush: enforce specific npm package version in monorepo service

Tags: typescript, monorepo, rush

we decided to start using rush as our monorepo tooling, however, we are having a specific issue here:

in mail service, we have "typescript": "^4.5.4" as devdependencies due to some breaking changes .... but other services use "typescript": "^3.9.10"..... whenever I run `rush update` and try `tsc -v` on mail service to check the version used, I keep getting typescript 3.9.10 displayed. my question is there a way to enforce rush to only use "typescript": "^4.5.4" for mail service specifically??.